# How to disable HTTP requests to Hadoop RPC port

Tags: http, hadoop, rpc

I have enabled security for my Hadoop cluster and it works fine. But when I visit the link http://namenode_host:8020, it shows:

```
It looks like you are making an HTTP request to a Hadoop IPC port. This is not the correct port for the web interface on this daemon.
```

But I don't want such behavior, because it is unencrypted message and the policy of our company is to encrypted the data for all the ports. 8020 is a RPC port of Hadoop. Any idea on how to disable HTTP requests to Hadoop RPC port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8020 - is the default port of Hadoop File System, which listens for the IPC calls from HDFS clients to Hadoop NameNode for HDFS metadata operations. You should not try to access it directly through HTTP. If you want to work with your data on HDFS through web you have to use [WebHDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html) API which allows to perform web requests upon the data in the file system.

Comment: Thanks Alex. But the thing is that the security team of my company will try access the port through HTTP, and tells me that it returns plain text without encryption. So is there any way to let it return through HTTPs or just don't return anything.

Comment: @WenyuanChen I don't think that your security team should bother with this as such request plays the role of a kind of a ping which just shows you that NameNode is up and running. You will not be able to get something else from your http request, so it does not really matter if it is plane text or not. If you really want to enable the encrypted dataflows within between HDFS and clients, you should follow the steps mentioned in the reference provided by Weiwei Yang

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Data Confidentiality](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html#Data_confidentiality) section from the apache doc, I think you are looking for the RPC encryption.

Comment: Yes. I have added the configuration. But the HTTP request to 8020 which is Hadoop RPC port still return the plain text message.

Comment: But the message you gave should not be concerned by your security team, it is just a message telling you this is a RPC port which is not supposed to be accessed by http request. Once you have PRC connection secured so that daemon communications (as well as client-server communications) through this port won't leak any data (encrypted).